# How to improve the performance with big state in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is what I wrote in react. it called game of life.

I make a cell as `div`, and store all the cell in one `state` object ,every cell has cell name look like "0_0", "0_1", "0_2" ....   and has own alive status and neighbor. so the `App` `state` looks like that:

[image]

and I make a time loop for check every cell's status.

but as you see, it with very bad performance although there are not so much cells in this case.

I thought it will get good performance by the virtual dom.

So how to improve the performance in this case?

```js
   
class Cell extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return nextProps.alive !== this.props.alive;
    }

    render() {
        let className = ['life'];
        if (this.props.alive) {
            className.push('alive');
        }

        return (
            <div className={className.join(' ')}></div>
        );
    }
}

let lifeSize = 5;
let w = 150;
let h = 150;
let chance = 0.75;
let stopTime = 333;
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        //this.cellsDiv=[];
        //console.log(store);
        this.checkAlive = this.checkAlive.bind(this);
        this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
        this.runTime = 1;


        //per_width = per_width < 5 ? 10 : per_width;
        for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(h / lifeSize); i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < parseInt(w / lifeSize); j++) {
                let neighborCells = [];
                neighborCells.push((i - 1) + '_' + (j - 1));
                neighborCells.push((i - 1) + '_' + (j + 1));
                neighborCells.push((i + 1) + '_' + (j - 1));
                neighborCells.push((i + 1) + '_' + (j + 1));
                neighborCells.push(i + '_' + (j - 1));
                neighborCells.push(i + '_' + (j + 1));
                neighborCells.push((i + 1) + '_' + j);
                neighborCells.push((i - 1) + '_' + j);
                this.state[i + '_' + j] = {};
                this.state[i + '_' + j]['alive'] = (Math.random() > chance);
                this.state[i + '_' + j]['neighbor'] = neighborCells;
            }
        }



    }
    checkAlive(cellName) {

        //console.log(neighborCells);
        let o = this.state[cellName];
        //console.log(i,j);
        let neighborCells = o['neighbor'];

        let alivecount = 0;
        for (let cell in neighborCells) {
            //console.log(neighborCells[cell],this.state[neighborCells[cell]]);
            if (this.state[neighborCells[cell]]) {
                if (this.state[neighborCells[cell]]['alive']) {
                    alivecount++;
                }
            }
        }
        //let alive = this.state[i + '_' + j]['alive'];
        //console.log(alive,alivecount);
        if (o['alive']) {
            if (alivecount < 2 || alivecount > 3) {
                o['alive'] = false;
            }
        } else {
            if (alivecount == 3) {
                o['alive'] = true;
            }
        }
        //console.log(o);
        let cells = {};
        cells[cellName] = {};
        cells[cellName]['alive'] = o['alive'];
        cells[cellName]['neighbor'] = o['neighbor'];
        this.setState(cells);
    }


    tick() {
        //console.log(this.runTime,stopTime);
        if (this.runTime >= stopTime) {
            clearInterval(this.timer);
        }
        
        //console.log(this.state);
        for (let cellName in this.state) {
            this.checkAlive(cellName);
        }

  this.runTime++;
        //console.log(this.state);
        //this.setState({alive:alive});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    render() {
    
        return (
            <div id="show">
            { Object.keys(this.state).map((k, index) => <Cell key={k} alive={this.state[k]['alive']}/>) }
   
   </div>
        );

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
#show {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  xbackground: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.life {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  xborder: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  float: left;
  xmargin: 1px;
}
.alive {
  background: black;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  xbackground: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is looking for *improvements/optimisations* and it belongs to [Code Reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You are abusing state, react has setState for a reason, so that you shouldn't manipulate it hard. For the rest, all frameworks have their intended usage, maybe a game isn't what react would be intended for

Comment: I would look into changing Cell's key property. At the moment you are passing  the whole object, trying giving a unique identifier as a string and see if that helps. I suspect passing an object as a key is causing you to lose any DOM rearrangement benefits you may (or may not) get.
Also, if you get Cell to extend React.PureComponent, you can get rid of your shouldComponentUpdate() function. (Shouldn't improve your performance in this case, but it's good to know)

Comment: @TMitchell I've check the key property,  `k` variable was string already.

Comment: @chanjianyi ahh right you are, I misread the Object.keys() part before .map(). 
Take a look at react performance tools. You can run the tool and find out if your components are re-rendering when they shouldn't be (and wasting time) - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html. If your components aren't wasting time re-rendering then perhaps you are trying to compute too much and might need to look at rethinking the structure of your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling this.setState for each cell.

Each time you call this.setState, render is called. You should delay this call.

Something like this:

```
let newState = {};
for (let cellName in this.state) {
    newState = {...newState, this.checkAlive(cellName)}; //remember removing the setState from checkAlive
}
this.setState(newState);
```

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to Diogo's answer I got a better performance now

although increase the cells and with faster time loop:

```js
class Cell extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return nextProps.alive !== this.props.alive;
    }

    render() {
        let className = ['life'];
        if (this.props.alive) {
            className.push('alive');
        }

        return (
            <div className={className.join(' ')}></div>
        );
    }
}

let cellSize = 5;
let w = 400;
let h = 400;
let chance = 0.85;
let stopTime = 200;
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        //this.cellsDiv=[];
        //console.log(store);
        this.checkAlive = this.checkAlive.bind(this);
        this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
        this.runTime = 1;


        //per_width = per_width < 5 ? 10 : per_width;
        for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(h / cellSize); i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < parseInt(w / cellSize); j++) {
                let neighborCells = [];
                neighborCells.push((i - 1) + '_' + (j - 1));
                neighborCells.push((i - 1) + '_' + (j + 1));
                neighborCells.push((i + 1) + '_' + (j - 1));
                neighborCells.push((i + 1) + '_' + (j + 1));
                neighborCells.push(i + '_' + (j - 1));
                neighborCells.push(i + '_' + (j + 1));
                neighborCells.push((i + 1) + '_' + j);
                neighborCells.push((i - 1) + '_' + j);
                this.state[i + '_' + j] = {};
                this.state[i + '_' + j]['alive'] = (Math.random() > chance);
                this.state[i + '_' + j]['neighbor'] = neighborCells;
            }
        }
         



    }
    checkAlive(cells,cellName) {

        //console.log(neighborCells);
        let o = this.state[cellName];
        //console.log(i,j);
        let neighborCells = o['neighbor'];

        let alivecount = 0;
        for (let cell in neighborCells) {
            //console.log(neighborCells[cell],this.state[neighborCells[cell]]);
            if (this.state[neighborCells[cell]]) {
                if (this.state[neighborCells[cell]]['alive']) {
                    alivecount++;
                }
            }
        }
        //let alive = this.state[i + '_' + j]['alive'];
        //console.log(alive,alivecount);
        if (o['alive']) {
            if (alivecount < 2 || alivecount > 3) {
                o['alive'] = false;
            }
        } else {
            if (alivecount == 3) {
                o['alive'] = true;
            }
        }
        //console.log(o);
        //let cells = {};
        cells[cellName] = {};
        cells[cellName]['alive'] = o['alive'];
        cells[cellName]['neighbor'] = o['neighbor'];
        return cells;       
 }


    tick() {
        //console.log(this.runTime,stopTime);
        if (this.runTime >= stopTime) {
            clearInterval(this.timer);
        }
    
 let newState = {};
        for (let cellName in this.state) {
     newState = this.checkAlive(newState,cellName);
        }
 this.setState(newState);
 this.runTime++;
     
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setInterval(this.tick, 500);
      
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    render() {
    
        return (
            <div id="show">
            { Object.keys(this.state).map((k, index) => <Cell key={k} alive={this.state[k]['alive']}/>) }
   
   </div>
        );

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
#show {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  xbackground: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.life {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  xborder: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  float: left;
  xmargin: 1px;
}
.alive {
  background: black;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  xbackground: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```